# How to pass parameter in a Java applet

Tags: java, applet

I am new to java and currently trying to create a code of passing parameter in java applet. Below is the code. While running the code the result is coming null. Can you friends can help me with rectification and suggestion.

Regards
Sandeep

```
    package Example_165_Applet_Fundamentals;

//Use parameters

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

/*
 * <applet code="Passing_Parameters_To_Applets" width=300 height=80>
 * <param name="fontName" value="Courier">
 * <param name="fontSize" value="14">
 * <param name="leading" value="2">
 * <param name="accountEnabled" value="true">
 * </applet>
 */
public class Passing_Parameters_To_Applets extends Applet
{
    String fontName;
    int fontSize;
    float leading;
    boolean active;

    //Initialize the string to be displayed
    public void start()
    {
        String param;

        fontName=getParameter("fontName");
        if(fontName==null)
        {
            fontName="Not Found";
        }

        param=getParameter("fontSize");
        try
        {
            if(param!=null)  //if not found
            {
                fontSize=Integer.parseInt(param);
            }
            else
            {
                fontSize=0;
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            fontSize=-1;
        }

        param=getParameter("leading");
        try
        {
            if(param!=null)  //if not found
            {
                leading=Float.valueOf(param).floatValue();
            }
            else
            {
                leading=0;
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            leading=-1;
        }

        param=getParameter("accountEnabled");
        if(param!=null)
        {
            active=Boolean.valueOf(param).booleanValue();
        }
    }
    //Display parameters
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Font Name: "+fontName, 0, 10);
        g.drawString("Font Size: "+fontSize, 0, 26);
        g.drawString("Leading: "+leading, 0, 42);
        g.drawString("Account Active: "+active, 0,58);
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html) may be of use to you.

Comment: The applet is apparently not being launched using the HTML defined in the Java source code.  What is the content of the HTML that launches it?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **getParameter()**, you should use **this.getParameter()**. I think that would work!

Comment: Hi I am using Eclipse Luna 64 bit as my IDE and also I have observed that the html file created in runtime by java RE is not having the param name and it's values. Can you guide me on that also.

Comment: So, how are you passing the parameters?

Comment: Hi I am passing the parameter as it is in the code above, but when I am running the result is showing null.

Comment: No, I mean that are you passing the parameters in some window of your IDE? If yes, the please post an image of it.

Comment: Hi no I am simply passing the param name from the above html code to the java applet. The code is the same what I have pasted above.